# Search algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, search

In Python, we can use `in` to search in strings, lists, sets, etc. like
`if x in string:`
But which search algorithm is internally implemented?

Comment: The duplicate only answers your question for strings, but the implementation is different for each type anyway. You might consider reading the source code for CPython for a specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The implemented search algorithm is at the vendor's discretion.  You need to consult your vendor's documentation for that.  Also note that the algorithm will vary by data type: unrestricted sequences will require some form of linear search; sorted ones will have bisection or interpolation; dicts and sets use a constant-time hash key.